# Timers and sysinfo at the character device driver in Linux

Tags: c, linux, timer, linux-device-driver, interrupt

I'm writing a simple character device driver in Linux. But I've encountered some issues. I've added timer but it's incorrect. I need to 1) execute timer one; 2) execute timer n times each 30 seconds apart and stop; 3) execute timer continuously until user sends a STOP command to the driver. And also the user process have to get back the data (snap shot) from device through command IO interface at the end of every timer interrupt completion. I can use jiffies, tasklets, interrupts but I have no idea how to implement them in this driver.
Then about the sysinfo(). I've added the code of sysinfo() to the user application but it has to be in the kernel application code and then send back the sysinfo() to the user application process and show in the terminal.
Here are my kernel and user application codes respectively.

Kernel:

```
/**
 * @file   diasdd.c
 * @date   16 May 2017
 * @version 0.1
 * @brief   This module maps to /dev/diasdd and
 * comes with a helper C program that can be run in Linux user space to communicate with
 * this the LKM.
 */

#include <linux/init.h>           // Macros used to mark up functions e.g. __init __exit
#include <linux/module.h>         // Core header for loading LKMs into the kernel
#include <linux/device.h>         // Header to support the kernel Driver Model
#include <linux/kernel.h>         // Contains types, macros, functions for the kernel
#include <linux/fs.h>             // Header for the Linux file system support
#include <asm/uaccess.h>          // Required for the copy to user function
#include <linux/timer.h>

#define  DEVICE_NAME "diasdd"    ///< The device will appear at /dev/diasdd using this value
#define  CLASS_NAME  "dd"        ///< The device class -- this is a character device driver

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");            ///< The license type -- this affects available functionality
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple Linux char driver");  ///< The description -- see modinfo
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");            ///< A version number to inform users

static int    majorNumber;                  ///< Stores the device number -- determined automatically
static char   message[256] = {0};           ///< Memory for the string that is passed from user space
static short  size_of_message;              ///< Used to remember the size of the string stored
static int    numberOpens = 0;              ///< Counts the number of times the device is opened
static struct class*  diasddClass  = NULL; ///< The device-driver class struct pointer
static struct device* diasddDevice = NULL; ///< The device-driver device struct pointer

// The prototype functions for the character driver -- must come before the struct definition
static int     dev_open(struct inode *, struct file *);
static int     dev_release(struct inode *, struct file *);
static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *);
static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *);

static struct timer_list my_timer;

void my_timer_callback( unsigned long data )
{
  printk( "DiasDD: my_timer_callback called (%ld).\n", jiffies );
}


/** @brief Devices are represented as file structure in the kernel. The file_operations structure from
 *  /linux/fs.h lists the callback functions that we wish to associated with our file operations
 *  using a C99 syntax structure. char devices usually implement open, read, write and release calls
 */
static struct file_operations fops =
{
   .open = dev_open,
   .read = dev_read,
   .write = dev_write,
   .release = dev_release,
};

/** @brief The LKM initialization function
 *  The static keyword restricts the visibility of the function to within this C file. The __init
 *  macro means that for a built-in driver (not a LKM) the function is only used at initialization
 *  time and that it can be discarded and its memory freed up after that point.
 *  @return returns 0 if successful
 */
static int __init diasdd_init(void){
    // Timer starts here
    int ret;

  printk("DiasDD: Timer module installing\n");

  // my_timer.function, my_timer.data
  setup_timer( &my_timer, my_timer_callback, 0 );

  printk( "DiasDD: Starting timer to fire in 300ms (%ld)\n", jiffies );
  ret = mod_timer( &my_timer, jiffies + msecs_to_jiffies(300) );
  if (ret) printk("Error in mod_timer\n");  

   printk(KERN_INFO "DiasDD: Initializing the DiasDD LKM\n");

   // Try to dynamically allocate a major number for the device -- more difficult but worth it
   majorNumber = register_chrdev(0, DEVICE_NAME, &fops);
   if (majorNumber<0){
      printk(KERN_ALERT "DiasDD failed to register a major number\n");
      return majorNumber;

   printk(KERN_INFO "DiasDD: registered correctly with major number %d\n", majorNumber);
   }

   // Register the device class
   diasddClass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, CLASS_NAME);
   if (IS_ERR(diasddClass)){                // Check for error and clean up if there is
      unregister_chrdev(majorNumber, DEVICE_NAME);
      printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to register device class\n");
      return PTR_ERR(diasddClass);          // Correct way to return an error on a pointer
   }
   printk(KERN_INFO "DiasDD: device class registered correctly\n");

   // Register the device driver
   diasddDevice = device_create(diasddClass, NULL, MKDEV(majorNumber, 0), NULL, DEVICE_NAME);
   if (IS_ERR(diasddDevice)){               // Clean up if there is an error
      class_destroy(diasddClass);           // Repeated code but the alternative is goto statements
      unregister_chrdev(majorNumber, DEVICE_NAME);
      printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to create the device\n");
      return PTR_ERR(diasddDevice);
   }
   printk(KERN_INFO "DiasDD: device class created correctly\n"); // Made it! device was initialized
   return 0;
}

/** @brief The LKM cleanup function
 *  Similar to the initialization function, it is static. The __exit macro notifies that if this
 *  code is used for a built-in driver (not a LKM) that this function is not required.
 */
static void __exit diasdd_exit(void){
    // Timer ends here
    int ret;

  ret = del_timer( &my_timer );
  if (ret) printk("DiasDD: The timer is still in use...\n");

  printk("DiasDD: Timer module uninstalling\n");

   device_destroy(diasddClass, MKDEV(majorNumber, 0));     // remove the device
   class_unregister(diasddClass);                          // unregister the device class
   class_destroy(diasddClass);                             // remove the device class
   unregister_chrdev(majorNumber, DEVICE_NAME);             // unregister the major number
   printk(KERN_INFO "DiasDD: Goodbye from the LKM!\n");
}

/** @brief The device open function that is called each time the device is opened
 *  This will only increment the numberOpens counter in this case.
 *  @param inodep A pointer to an inode object (defined in linux/fs.h)
 *  @param filep A pointer to a file object (defined in linux/fs.h)
 */
static int dev_open(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep){
   numberOpens++;
   printk(KERN_INFO "DiasDD: Device has been opened %d time(s)\n", numberOpens);
   return 0;
}

/** @brief This function is called whenever device is being read from user space i.e. data is
 *  being sent from the device to the user. In this case it uses the copy_to_user() function to
 *  send the buffer string to the user and captures any errors.
 *  @param filep A pointer to a file object (defined in linux/fs.h)
 *  @param buffer The pointer to the buffer to which this function writes the data
 *  @param len The length of the b
 *  @param offset The offset if required
 */
static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *filep, char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset){
   int error_count = 0;
   // copy_to_user has the format ( * to, *from, size) and returns 0 on success
   error_count = copy_to_user(buffer, message, size_of_message);

   if (error_count==0){            // if true then have success
      printk(KERN_INFO "DiasDD: Sent %d characters to the user\n", size_of_message);
      return (size_of_message=0);  // clear the position to the start and return 0
   }
   else {
      printk(KERN_INFO "DiasDD: Failed to send %d characters to the user\n", error_count);
      return -EFAULT;              // Failed -- return a bad address message (i.e. -14)
   }
}

/** @brief This function is called whenever the device is being written to from user space i.e.
 *  data is sent to the device from the user. The data is copied to the message[] array in this
 *  LKM using the sprintf() function along with the length of the string.
 *  @param filep A pointer to a file object
 *  @param buffer The buffer to that contains the string to write to the device
 *  @param len The length of the array of data that is being passed in the const char buffer
 *  @param offset The offset if required
 */
static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filep, const char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset){
   sprintf(message, "%s(%zu letters)", buffer, len);   // appending received string with its length
   size_of_message = strlen(message);                 // store the length of the stored message
   printk(KERN_INFO "DiasDD: Received %zu characters from the user\n", len);
   printk(KERN_INFO "DiasDD: Received message: %s\n", buffer);
   return len;
}

/** @brief The device release function that is called whenever the device is closed/released by
 *  the user space program
 *  @param inodep A pointer to an inode object (defined in linux/fs.h)
 *  @param filep A pointer to a file object (defined in linux/fs.h)
 */
static int dev_release(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep){
   printk(KERN_INFO "DiasDD: Device successfully closed\n");
   return 0;
}

/** @brief A module must use the module_init() module_exit() macros from linux/init.h, which
 *  identify the initialization function at insertion time and the cleanup function (as

 *  listed above)
 */
module_init(diasdd_init);
module_exit(diasdd_exit);
```

User Process:

```
/**
 * @file   testdiasdd.c
 * @date   16 May 2017
 * @version 0.1
 * @brief  A Linux user space program that communicates with the diasdd.c LKM. It passes a
 * string to the LKM and reads the response from the LKM. For this example to work the device
 * must be called /dev/diasdd.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/sysinfo.h>    // sysinfo
#include <unistd.h>     // sysconf

#define BUFFER_LENGTH 256               ///< The buffer length (crude but fine)
static char receive[BUFFER_LENGTH];     ///< The receive buffer from the LKM

int main(){
   int ret, fd;
   char stringToSend[BUFFER_LENGTH];
   printf("Starting device test code example...\n");
   fd = open("/dev/diasdd", O_RDWR);             // Open the device with read/write access
   if (fd < 0){
      perror("Failed to open the device...");
      return errno;
   }
   printf("Type in a short string to send to the kernel module:\n");
   scanf("%[^\n]%*c", stringToSend);                // Read in a string (with spaces)
   printf("Writing message to the device [%s].\n", stringToSend);
   ret = write(fd, stringToSend, strlen(stringToSend)); // Send the string to the LKM
   if (ret < 0){
      perror("Failed to write the message to the device.");
      return errno;
   }

   printf("Press ENTER to read back from the device...\n");
   getchar();

   printf("Reading from the device...\n");
   ret = read(fd, receive, BUFFER_LENGTH);        // Read the response from the LKM
   if (ret < 0){
      perror("Failed to read the message from the device.");
      return errno;
   }
   printf("The received message is: [%s]\n", receive);
   printf("End of the program\n");

   struct sysinfo info;

     if (sysinfo(&info) != 0)

    printf("\n");
    printf("Current system info:\n");
    printf("Uptime: %ld:%ld:%ld\n", info.uptime/3600, info.uptime%3600/60, info.uptime%60);
    printf("Total RAM: %ld MB\n", info.totalram/1024/1024);
    printf("Free RAM: %ld MB\n", (info.totalram-info.freeram)/1024/1024);
    printf("Shared RAM: %ld MB\n", info.sharedram/1024/1024);
    printf("Memory used by buffers: %ld MB\n", info.bufferram/1024/1024);
    printf("Free swap space size: %ld bytes\n", info.freeswap);
    printf("Process count: %d\n", info.procs);

   return 0;
 }
```

This is my Makefile:

```
obj-m := diasdd.o 

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
        $(CC) testdiasdd.c -o test
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
        rm test
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn how to debug code.

Comment: The codes run correctly but I need to add timers and sysinfo() which I've added in wrong place and improperly.

Comment: Too many problems in one question post. At least on problem - `sysinfo` - is not related with others. 3 scenarios for timer - "once", "n times", "until stopped" are also distinct problems. `And also the user process have to get back the data (snap shot) from device through command IO interface at the end of every timer interrupt completion.` - How this should operate from the user's point of view? Should `ioctl()` return data after 300ms, and user should call it again for get new portion of data? Currently, you question is **too broad** for Stack Overflow format.

Comment: I understand that it's sophisticated. However, if you can help with one of these problems, I would be thankful.